# How to create a cross-validation fold variable via createFolds function in caret?

Tags: r, r-caret, cross-validation

How do I create a variable, fold, in my analysis dataset which is assigned the values of 1:k from the `createFolds` cross-validation function in `caret`?

For example using the following college admissions dataset:

```
# Load data.
mydata <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
folds <- createFolds(mydata$admit, k=5)

# Create variable "mydata$fold" and assign values of 1:5 to mydata$fold.
?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this with `createFolds`, it has an argument `list` which defaults to `TRUE` giving a list of the indicies in each fold. If you change it to `FALSE` the function returns a vector of the folds that each row is being assigned to.

```
folds <- createFolds(mydata$admit, k=5,list = FALSE)
```

See `?createFolds` for more details.

Comment: Ah got it - run: folds <- createFolds(mydata$admit, k=5,list = FALSE); mydata <- cbind(mydata, folds). Thank you!